# Using while/for to read only two lines of input

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, i got a problem that comes with 2 lines of input

Input :
4 6 |
6 9

Output :
2 | 15

(the "|" would be an line break)

but i don't know how i'm supposed to read those two lines

i've tried using for, limiting i < 2; 
it would give me the correct answer, but if the input has more than 2 lines it won't work (obviously); 
so i want to know what i need to use (while/for) and how to use it

```
var lines = input.split('\n');

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    var nums = lines[i].split(" ");

    var n1 = Number(nums[0]);
    var n2 = Number(nums[1]);

    var mofiz = n1 ^ n2;

    console.log(mofiz);
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Do you know how arrays work? For example using "split" will return an array. The number of elements (lines) in that array can be obtained through its "length" property : lines.length (which in your case would return 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was pretty good overall, you just need to define the limit of your counter "i" as the length of your array "lines" :

```js
const input = "2 3\n2 5\n6 7"


var lines = input.split('\n');

//you should always define your variables, even in a loop
for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    var nums = lines[i].split(" ");

    var n1 = Number(nums[0]);
    var n2 = Number(nums[1]);
    
    //just so you know you are performing a logical xor, and not an exponentiation which is ** (a**b or Math.pow(a, b))
    var mofiz = n1 ^ n2;

    console.log(mofiz);
}
```

Comment: Cool pointer about logical xor, but the OP seems to have specified xor results in the example output up above.

Answer (score 0):

`while` loops and `for` loops are equivalent.  These two versions of the code will do the exact same thing:

`for` loop version:

```
var lines = input.split('\n');

for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    var nums = lines[i].split(" ");

    var n1 = Number(nums[0]);
    var n2 = Number(nums[1]);

    var mofiz = n1 ^ n2;

    console.log(mofiz);
}
```

`while` loop version:

```
var lines = input.split('\n');

i = 0;
while(i < lines.length){
    var nums = lines[i].split(" ");

    var n1 = Number(nums[0]);
    var n2 = Number(nums[1]);

    var mofiz = n1 ^ n2;

    console.log(mofiz);
    i++;
}
```

As for your actual problem: you need to use the `length` property (`lines.length`) to determine how many times the loop should run.

Comment: `for` loops and `while` loops are absolutely not equivalent! By many reasons, being the last one much best performant.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano The two forms are defined to do the exact some thing.  Performance differences, if they exist at all, will depend on the platform you're running them on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the first two lines, you can simply destructure them from your array.

```
const [firstLine, secondLine] = input.split('\n');
console.log('First:', firstLine);
console.log('Second:', secondLine);
// now go calculate the `mofiz` thing, whatever it is.
```

Anyway, if you want to loop over all the lines, you can either use `lines.forEach` or `map` or whatever suits you, e.g. to print, you use forEach

```
const lines = input.split('\n');
lines.forEach(line => {
  const [firstNumber, secondNumber] = line.split(' ');
  const mofiz = firstNumber ^ secondNumber;
  console.log(mofiz);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to just calculate all the `mofiz` things, and print them all together somewhere else, you'd use a `map`:

```
const lines = input.split('\n');
const mofizes = lines.map(line => {
  const [firstNumber, secondNumber] = line.split(' ');
  return firstNumber ^ secondNumber;
});
console.log(mofizes); // prints "[2, 15]"
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be one of the correct ways of doing what you want (explanation below):

```
'use strict';

let i = 0;
let length = null;
let input = `
1 0
1 1
0 0
0 1
`;
let val = 0;
let chr = '';
let count = 0;

input = input.split(/(?=[\s\S])/u);
length = input.length;

while (i < length) {
    if (input[i] !== '\n') {
        if (input[i] !== ' ') {
            chr += input[i];
        } else if (chr !== '') {
            count++;
            val ^= parseInt(chr);
            chr = '';
        }
    } else {
        if (chr !== '') {
            val ^= parseInt(chr);
            chr = '';
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(val);
            count = 0;
            val = 0
        }
    }
    i++;
}

// OUTPUT:
//  1
//  0
//  0
//  1
```

Basically I used `input = input.split(/(?=[\s\S])/u);` to split the whole input by each character to then dynamically process the array in a single scan.

1. Creating less variables and initializing them outside loops improves performance (memory and speed).
2. Using Number() constructor to spawn numbers in JavaScript is highly discouraged, it has terrible performance, compared with direct primitives usage or other methods, and could lead to problems when comparing with other elements. Use `parseInt()` instead in this case.
3. As said by other users, using Array.length is the way you get the number of iterations to make.
4. Written this way, your code is less syntax dependant. It would be able to handle longer lines, with multiple whitespaces, and do other operations (by only changing `'^='` with `'*='`, `'**='`, `'+='`, `'-='`, etc)

***LAST EDIT (see previous version for simplicity)***

- `for` replaced with `while`
- Multiple digits numbers accepted (EX: 42 3 19)

Comment: Such minute optimization is irrelevant in this case.  Making the code so complex, on the other hand, is not.  You really shouldn't be answering what appears to be a homework question with such hard-to-understand code.

Comment: I just benchmarked your heavily-optimized code against the simpler versions in my answer and yours came up 32% slower.  I think you did a poor job of optimizing it.

Comment: @Brilliand First of all, my function manages lines with any length, and yours not (that is a big difference), also, your code breaks if more than one space or line break is used, mine doesn't. Finally, I used a `for` loop, which I've already told you in your answer, is not equivalent to a `while` loop and is less performant. There is your 32%.

Comment: @Brilliand Additionally, your function logs two extra no-sense results (one at the beginning, and one at the end).

Comment: My goal was to answer the question while changing his code as little as possible.  Your goal appeared to be to optimize the code, but you... didn't do that.  Adding features that weren't asked for is no excuse.

Comment: @Brilliand Are you sure you read the benchmark results correctly? According to [THIS](https://jsbench.me/x2jx10jxq9/1), MINE is more performant than YOURS (by 32%) and does a lot more things... I even did't change my `for` loop for a `while` and I'm running in strict mode. I bet I could easily reach 40%. If you are going to downvote someone... do it well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195090/discussion-between-brilliand-and-ernesto-stifano).

Answer (score -2):

As per OP question title:

> Using while/for to read only two lines of input

You don’t need a loop to accomplish such an easy task.

```js
    var INSTR = '0 1 2\n3 4 5\n6 7 8\n9 ...';
    var lines = /^([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/.exec(INSTR);
    console.log(lines[1]);
    console.log(lines[2]);
```

Comment: Your RegExp is missing a parenthesis, `console.print()` does not exist in JavaScript or Node, and in any case, your code would't do what OP wants to do.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Made edit to the code. Must had made a mistake, it is hard to do code on mobile.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Some thoughts on **in any case, your code would't do what OP wants to do**. I'm not a native speaker. I had a writing/speaking class once. It taught me some thing. One of such thing is that good topic, starting with question, must consist of: `the question`; `supporting paragraphs`. I see `the question` in OP post. I answered it. His other statements belong to the aforementioned `supporting paragraphs`. It is his thoughts, his errors and trials and so on. He even got the `input`/`expected output` part wrong. So I just skiped it. Thats it. I don't read what I don't need to.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano And yes, I have read the topic few times. Still do not see in what part I did not get the **in any case, your code would't do what OP wants to do**. OP wants to read two lines of input. He gets that. That's it.